# LinkedIn API :: how to obtain the bearer access token

Tags: rest, get, postman, linkedin-api

It's not easy to use the official LinkedIn API and I cannot find a valid documentation.

Following the [official documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/) I created a new application in order to obtain the Client ID and Client Secret

When I now make a POST call through Postman to  https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken this is what I obtain:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant_type",
    "error_description": "The passed in grant_type is invalid"
}
```

[image]

Where am I wrong?

> **EDIT AFTER HELP FROM @Amit Singh**

Thanks to @AmitSingh I was able to create 2 different applications, the test with the **Client Credentials flow** gave me as a result an error retrieving the token:

[image]

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}
```

When I try to use the **LinkedIn 3-legged workflow** I receive `Unauthorized`

[image]

EDIT 3: GETTING THERE THROUGH POSTMAN

I now see that I can ask Postman to do the job, however when I press on `Get New Access Token` it opens an error page. I believe the error might be in these 4 elements:

[image]

- `Token name`: maybe I have to give a special token name?
- `Auth URL`: I set `https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback` as explained [here](https://gist.github.com/1951FDG/bf589ac915dfa9a3c14cb284c73093cd) but maybe I have to set something else?
- `Access Token URL`: I left it blank, maybe I have to put something here?
- `State`: I set a random string like `Hello123Boy` but maybe I have to put something else. Maybe is too long. Maybe is too short. Maybe it has to contain symbols, etc... ?

...Also, in the [guide you linked](https://gist.github.com/1951FDG/bf589ac915dfa9a3c14cb284c73093cd) it says that the applicatoin needs to have:

- r_liteprofile
- rw_company_admin
- w_member_social

mine has nothing:

[image]

Being recently created is still under review. It says it can take up to 90 days. Is that true?

[image]

> **4th EDIT: I WANT TO BELIEVE!**

Here we are, at least now I'm getting the error: `Bummer, something went wrong. The redirect_uri does not match the registered value`. This is amazing: finally an error that says where the problem is!

[image]

On the app the, on the Products tab, I choose `Sign In with LinkedIn`. As
Authorized redirect URLs for your app I set `https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback`

[image]

In Postman I setup `Auth URL` and `Access Token URL` as you said:

[image]

Comment: if you want to browse documentation in general - here's the official source: https://www.linkedin.com/developers/

Comment: @timur thank you, the documentation is very unpractical, that's why I'm asking this question. I will now add the specific error.

Comment: you don't seem to be passing `redirect_uri` and `code` to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken` - i believe both [are required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/consumer/context#step-3-exchange-authorization-code-for-an-access-token)

Comment: @timur, those are for step 3, I'm still stuck in step 2 with the bearer token. If you have a solution just post it

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: @AmitSingh, I'm sure timur's code should work. Probably the problem is on my side that I don't know how to use Postman properly. That's why I need someone that teach me step by step how to use Postman to obtain the access and query LinkedIn API. I can import the JSON to Postman and I see the 4 queries that timur wrote for me but still I don't know ow to make the code run. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: One clear issue that I see here is that your `grant_type` is set to your email ID where as the documentation explicitly says that it should be set to `client_credentials` and nothing else.

Comment: Documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow#step-2-generate-an-access-token Check the first row of the table.

Comment: Thank you @AmitSingh but it would be easier if you post a solution. Because now I have several questions 1) what `client_credentials` means? Should I put `email:password` or `email&password` or just `email` or just `password`? 2) What about `client_id`? An example would be easier and will be less back and forward for everyone. I just want to have some code that I can paste and works

Comment: Auth URL should be set to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization` and access token URL should be set to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken`. Token name and state can be anything no issues with that.

Comment: LinkedIn OAuth's are added based on what LinkedIn products are integrated with your app. Select the (Sign In with LinkedIn)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin] for access to `r_liteprofile` and `r_emailaddress`. Marketing APIs need approval from LinkedIn before they can be used by you. Request for the `Sign In with LinkedIn` for those scopes.

Comment: Note that `Sign In With LinkedIn` and `Share on LinkedIn` do not require approval and they have the basic scopes that you might want. For more info, check their docs.

Comment: Thank you @AmitSingh, `Sign in with LinkedIn` requires approval https://snipboard.io/SRoLEz.jpg . Anyway, I feel I'm getting there. I will let you know

Comment: I updated my question again. Take your time @AmitSingh, I will relaunch the bounty if it expires. Thank you for your kind help

Comment: I think it will be better if we move this chat into a chat room instead of addressing it here. That will save someone coming to this thread for some help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226780/discussion-between-amit-singh-and-francesco-mantovani).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### LinkedIn Credential workflows

LinkedIn offers 2 different credential workflows.

1. **[LinkedIn 3-legged workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow)** - When you want to use an API that will access LinkedIn member's data. *Authorization Code grant type needed*.
2. **[LinkedIn Client Credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow)** - When you want to use an API that will access non-member resources. *Client credentials grant needed*.

### What are grant types?

"Grant type" refers to how you have acquired an access token in an OAuth workflow.

Several grant types are supported. Some of them are:

1. **[Client Credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4)** - Used when you want to access your own resources and not any other users
2. **[Authorization Code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2)** - Used when an app wants to access a client's data
3. **[Refresh token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5)** - Exchange an expired access token for a valid access token, used to avoid repeated user involvement
4. **[Password](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3)** - Used when there is high trust between the app and the user e.g. LinkedIn mobile app, you provide your username and password

### Client Credentials flow

#### What you need to know

- Grant type used here is Client credentials - `client_credentials`.
- Remember to set your `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for all POST requests in OAuth.

#### Steps

1. Create an App and get your Client ID and Client Secret. Steps are shown in the respective docs linked above. Let's say they have values - `<client_id>` and `<client_secret>`.
2. Send a POST required to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken` with following information.

   *Parameters*

   ```yaml
   grant_type : client_credentials
   client_id  : <client_id>
   client_secret : <client_secret>
   ```

   **NOTE :** `client_credentials` is the literal text to be entered for `grant_type`.

   Response will return a JSON Object containing your access token and its expiry duration in seconds.

   *Response*

   ```js
   {
      "access_token" : <access_token>,
      "expires_in" : "1800"
   }
   ```
3. Use the `<access_token>` obtained in Step 2 make API requests.

   *Example*

   ```
   Request URL: https://www.linkedin.com/v2/jobs
   Request type: GET

   Parameters
   Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
   ```

### LinkedIn 3-legged workflow

#### What you need to know

- Grant type will be Authorization code - `code`, since you want to access a user's data.
- Your `Content-Type` should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for all POST requests in OAuth.
- [Redirect URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2) are URLs where you OAuth server will redirect the user after successful authorization.

  - These are verified against your provided redirect URLs to ensure that it's not fraudulent.
  - These should be absolute URLs.
  - URL arguments are ignored and cannot include a `#`.

#### Steps

1. Create app and provide the Redirect URLs, if not already provided. Check [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow) for information regarding how to do this.
2. Get your Client ID and Client Secret. Let's say the values are `<client_id>` and `<client_secret>`.
3. Generate a random, hard to guess string. Let's say it's `<random-string>`.
4. Choose one of the redirect URLs provided in Step 1, where you want user to be redirected after authorization. Let's say it is `<redirect_uri>`.
5. Let's suppose you want to:

   - `r_emailaddress` - Get his email address
   - `w_member_social` - Post, comment and like posts on behalf of the user.

   These are referred as "permission scopes", as in what permissions is the user authenticating you for. When sending these scopes in your request, they should be URL-encoded and space-delimited. In this particular instance, our scope will be `scope: r_emailaddress%20w_member_social`. We have URL-encoded the scopes mentioned above.

   Adding more information regarding scopes from the Microsoft docs:

   > The scopes available to your app depend on which Products or Partner Programs your app has access to.  Your app's Auth tab will show current scopes available. You can apply for new Products under the Products tab. If approved, your app will have access to new scopes.
6. Send a POST request to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization` with following information.

   *Parameters*

   ```yaml
   response_type : code
   client_id  : <client_id>
   redirect_uri : <redirect_uri>
   state : <random_string>
   scope : r_emailaddress%20w_member_social
   ```
7. After the request, the user will be presented with LinkedIn's Auth screen and asked to approve the request.
8. After user approves the request and the `<redirect_uri>` has been verified, user will be redirected to provided `<redirect_uri>` along with the access code `<access_code>` and a value in `state` argument. Let's say in the state argument is `<state_value>`.
9. Verify that the `<state_value>` is equal to the `<random_string>` before working with the `<access_code>` to get access token, for security purposes. Also, use the `<access_code>` within 30 minutes of being issued, for security reasons.
10. Next, send a POST request to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken` with following information to get the access token.

    *Parameters*

    ```yaml
    grant_type : authorization_code
    client_id  : <client_id>
    client_secret : <client_secret>
    redirect_uri : <redirect_uri>
    code : <access_code>
    ```

    **NOTE** : `authorization_code` is the literal text to be passed in `grant_type`.

    You should get a similar response as in the Client Credentials workflow containing your access token and expiry duration.

    *Response*

    ```js
    {
       "access_token" : <access_token>,
       "expires_in" : "1800"
    }
    ```
11. Use the `<access_token>` obtained in Step 9 make API requests.

    *Example*

    ```
    Request URL: `https://www.linkedin.com/v2/me`
    Request type: GET

    Parameters:
    Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
    ```

### How to do this in Postman?

1. Create a new Collection.
2. Right click, select edit collection and move to authorization tab.
3. In "Type", select "OAuth2.0", click on "Get New Access Token".
4. You will see a screen where all the familiar terms mentioned above are there. Fill those, check the "Authorize via Browser" checkbox for authorization.
5. Now you have the access token and can proceed to make your API calls.

Postman has been designed to make such operations easier, but you have to know how to do it. For more details, you can read their [official docs](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#oauth-20).

Comment: Thank you, is all much clear now. My goal is to retrieve informations from LinkedIn users profile. Cannot believe LinkedIn API is so hard to use. I created 2 different API but none of them works. Maybe the problem is the redirect URL I'm using `https://www.jeeja.biz` ? Or maybe the `Products` tab in the LinkedIn application?

Comment: What I did see was that the grant type is incorrect. What step are you getting stuck in? Is the redirection happening? Ideally, I would expect it to redirect and then throw the error even if it's an incorrect redirection. @FrancescoMantovani

Comment: Since your redirect URI is `https://www.jeeja.biz`, you would be getting a request like `https://www.jeeja.biz?code=dkafjkakf&state=dkfkafa` and your web server listening at the endpoint should process it from Step 10.

Comment: Can you confirm that what I need in order to dig the users' profiles is LinkedIn 3-legged workflow  and not the LinkedIn Client Credentials flow. Because I want to scrap users

Comment: If you want to get person's profile data, you need his approval and for that you need the 3-legged workflow. This is mentioned in the Profile API doc which provides you this information. Just click on the authentication call link and it redirects to the 3-legged workflow. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani Did not know that you had added further details in the question. Have updated the answer to show the steps for Postman too. This flow is common to both the Client Credentials flow and the 3-legged workflow.

Comment: I also found a gist showing this workflow now that might help you out. https://gist.github.com/1951FDG/bf589ac915dfa9a3c14cb284c73093cd

Comment: When I hit the "authorization" API and login with user credentials. I got the error "Not found: checkpoint/lg/login-submit", Do you have any idea why I am getting that?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @timur and @AmitSingh I finally arrived to authenticate to LinkedIn API.

A brief step by step solution in pictures:

- Authorized redirect URLs for your app = `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback`
- OAuth 2.0 scopes = must have `r_emailaddress` and `r_liteprofile`
- In the Products Tab set `Sign In with LinkedIn`

[image]

Now open Postman > Collections > New Collection > Authorization and set the parameters as in picture:

[image]

- TYPE = `OAUTH 2.0`
- Token Name = put whatever you want
- Callback URL = `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback` (should be greyed out once you tick `Authorize using browser`)
- Tick `Authorize using browser`
- Auth URL = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization`
- Access Token URL = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken`
- Client ID = The Client ID you find on your LinkedIn App
- Client Secret = The Client Secret you find on your LinkedIn App
- Scope = `r_liteprofile` `r_emailaddress`
- State = put whatever you like

Now click on `Get New Access Token`, a page will open on your browser and you will be able to login using your LinkedIn account. Once done you are authenticated.

Now use the code provided by @timur and on Postman go to Import > Upload File and import that .JSON file. You will now have the 4 queries and you can drag and drop them in your collection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've created your app, added correct redirect URL and enabled "[Sign In with LinkedIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin)" product for your app, the issue you are having is probably that the first call returns a login page where your users are supposed to authenticate.

1. submit the request to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization` (you seem to have done that)
2. parse response of step 1 and extract all form values, add username and password to simulate user login
3. make POST request and use values from previous step as `x-www-form-urlencoded` data
4. manually follow the redirect header from step 3
5. make note of second redirect header but do not follow it - instead extract the code
6. POST code from previous step to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken` and get access_token in response

From here, I was able to successfully transition to the auth code by following the steps.
I am not sure if you use the online Postman, but here's my complete collection export file for reference:

```json
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "397761c9-4287-43f2-860a-3c34cb710d50",
        "name": "Linkedin oAuth",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "01 request Login form",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text());\r",
                            "var inputs = $('form').serializeArray();\r",
                            "var payload = '';\r",
                            "inputs.forEach(i => {\r",
                            "    payload += encodeURIComponent(i.name)+ '=' + encodeURIComponent(i.value) + '&';\r",
                            "})\r",
                            "payload += 'session_key='+ encodeURIComponent(pm.collectionVariables.get('username')) + '&'\r",
                            "payload += 'session_password='+ encodeURIComponent(pm.collectionVariables.get('password'))\r",
                            "\r",
                            "pm.collectionVariables.set(\"form_data\", payload);"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={{client_id}}&redirect_uri={{redirect_uri}}&scope=r_liteprofile&state={{$guid}}",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "www",
                        "linkedin",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "oauth",
                        "v2",
                        "authorization"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "response_type",
                            "value": "code"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "client_id",
                            "value": "{{client_id}}"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "redirect_uri",
                            "value": "{{redirect_uri}}"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "scope",
                            "value": "r_liteprofile"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "state",
                            "value": "{{$guid}}"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "02 Submit login form",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "var url = 'https://www.linkedin.com'+ pm.response.headers.get(\"Location\");\r",
                            "pm.collectionVariables.set('first_redirect', url);\r",
                            "//console.log(pm.collectionVariables.get('first_redirect'));"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "followRedirects": false
            },
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "{{form_data}}",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "text"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/lg/login-submit",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "www",
                        "linkedin",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "checkpoint",
                        "lg",
                        "login-submit"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "03 handle login-success redirect",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "var sdk = require('postman-collection');\r",
                            "var redirect = new sdk.Url(pm.response.headers.get(\"Location\"));\r",
                            "pm.collectionVariables.set('code', redirect.query.filter(q => q.key === 'code').map(k => k.value)[0]);\r",
                            "//console.log(pm.collectionVariables.get('code'));"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "console.log(pm.variables.get('first_redirect'));\r",
                            "pm.request.url.update(pm.variables.get('first_redirect'));"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "followRedirects": false
            },
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "{{first_redirect}}",
                    "host": [
                        "{{first_redirect}}"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "04 Get Auth Code",
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code={{code}}&redirect_uri={{redirect_uri}}&client_id={{client_id}}&client_secret={{client_secret}}",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "www",
                        "linkedin",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "oauth",
                        "v2",
                        "accessToken"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "grant_type",
                            "value": "authorization_code"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "code",
                            "value": "{{code}}"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "redirect_uri",
                            "value": "{{redirect_uri}}"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "client_id",
                            "value": "{{client_id}}"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "client_secret",
                            "value": "{{client_secret}}"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "event": [
        {
            "listen": "prerequest",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "listen": "test",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "variable": [
        {
            "key": "client_id",
            "value": "your app id"
        },
        {
            "key": "client_secret",
            "value": "your app secret"
        },
        {
            "key": "redirect_uri",
            "value": "your urlencoded redirect uri such as https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080"
        },
        {
            "key": "username",
            "value": "user login"
        },
        {
            "key": "password",
            "value": "user password"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't have any app, I have to do this through Postman. The problem I believe is in step 1: I haven't queried https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization . 
Can you just give me a step by step in Postman, please? From point 1 to point 6. Thank you

Comment: well, these are the steps - can you import the json into your postman?

Comment: It says I cannot import JSON into Postman

Comment: what version postman are you using? mine happily picked it up with File->Import dialog

Comment: This is my problem on the latest Postaman: https://snipboard.io/mw1eqv.jpg

Comment: don't you have this item in your "File" menu? https://snipboard.io/JP4ZeO.jpg

Comment: yeah but the result is the same, it opens up the same upload page, in which I upload a test.json file and it returns me the same error

Comment: Hi, I arrived to import, I had to do Import > Raw text. Now where to add the value to the variables?

Comment: you probably want to create an environment and set all variables under there

Comment: OK, i set client_id and client_secret but what about redirect_uri and code? What about first_redirect and $guid?

Comment: You need to set client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, username and password. Other variables should get created by steps when you run them

Comment: Thank you  for your patience @timur. What should I put as redirect_uri? I don't find the variables username and password by the way

Comment: You define redirect_uri in developer console, `https:// localhost` is totally acceptable for development purposes

Comment: Very blurry, let me know if you need an higher quality https://youtu.be/sIVyl2FnGEE

Comment: You need to supply user login and password to authenticate to LinkedIn on second step. As I said in the answer, it sends you a login form that users would normally use to authenticate. Since that's you doing the test - it might as well be your linkedin creds

Comment: Also, you might want to get a general overview of oAuth protocol. I believe [Auth0 have good tutorials](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/authorization-code-flow) on the topic

Comment: But there are no variables for user/password

Comment: There are, check the end of JSON file and test code for step 02

Comment: Thank you. I edited that part but I receive the same error. What if I pay you 50NZD and you teach me through a Skype session how to do it? It will no take more than 10 minutes I believe. Let me know